# Splash screen doesn't disappear on some devices

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an issue, i wrote a application and tested it on simulator and some devices, everything was fine, but on some devices (on IPhone 5) i saw only launch image and nothing else. What's the problem?

Comment: By 'splash' you mean default? What debugging have you done? What does your app do when it finishes launching?

Comment: yes, the default image, after showing it it'll go to webview

Comment: @Anton All iPhone5 or just some? Try to double check your Info.plist, the "Launch Image" section, e.g. Default or Default.png. Thus, you should add `Default-568h@2x.png` to support iPhone 5 screen

Comment: Clean project in Xcode before archive new distribution binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is really weird, cause in some devices everything is fine, in some devices not.
In the beginning I used ARC, and when i rebuilt project without ARC, the bug was fixed. Maybe there is some problem in device or elsewhere, don't really know.

Answer (score 1):

The launch image should disappear on it's own. Try to NSLog on viewDidLoad of the root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you splash screen image name is for

```
IS_IPHONE_5  = @"Default-568h@2x.png"
IS_IPHONE_4  = @"Default.png"
```

Comment: they are, the problem is that application works fine on some devices but on the others don't

Comment: how can remove your splash ??

Comment: The launch image should disappear on it's own, but it won't

Answer (score 0):

I think you can drag and drop the splash screen image to launch image   4in  [image]

Answer (score -1):

Try to do this way,
Write **sleep(no.of seconds);**
in app delegate did finish launching options method.It is work for me.
Hope this helps to You.

Comment: i don't need a delay for default image, i need to hide somehow the default (launch) image